# How to stop a software with a timer repeat over and over?

Tags: java, timer

I have created a software timer and when it goes zero it's going to start a new login screen. The problem is the login comes over and over again. How to stop this?

```
class DisplayCountdown extends TimerTask {

    int seconds = 0005;

    public void run() {
        if (seconds > 0) {
            int hr = (int) (seconds / 3600);
            int rem = (int) (seconds % 3600);
            int mn = rem / 60;
            int sec = rem % 60;
            String hrStr = (hr < 10 ? "0" : "") + hr;
            String mnStr = (mn < 10 ? "0" : "") + mn;
            String secStr = (sec < 10 ? "0" : "") + sec;
            seconds--;
            lab.setText(hrStr + " : " + mnStr + " : " + secStr + "");
        } else {
            login ty = new login();
            login.scname.setText(scname.getText());
            login.scnum.setText(scnum.getText());
            login.mar.setText(jTextField1.getText());
            ty.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is violating the single thread rules of Swing - Updating the UI out side the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Instead of `TimerTask`, you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.

```
javax.swing.Timer swingTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (seconds > 0) {
            //...
        } else {
            ((javax.swing.Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
            //...
        }
    }
});
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what the code is but can't you use the "cancel()" method of the TimerTask class to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep reference of previous Login Screen and dispose it before making a new one;